# Weak derivative of positive part of Sobolev function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I've been looking through the notes on Sobolev Spaces here: [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/pdes/ch3.pdf)

Proposition 3.22 states that if $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ has weak derivative $\partial_i u \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ then:
$$\partial_i |u|=\begin{cases} 
\partial_i u & u> 0 \\
0 & u=0 \\
-\partial_i u & u<0 
\end{cases}
$$

The notes then mention that an immediate corollary of this result is that:
$$\partial_i u^+=\begin{cases} 
\partial_i u & u> 0 \\
0 & u\leq0 
\end{cases}
$$

However, when I made the same computation, I arrived at:
$$\partial_i u^+=\begin{cases} 
\partial_i u & u> 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\partial_i u & u=0 \\
0 & u<0 
\end{cases}
$$

Is my calculation correct? If so, are the two formulations equivalent?

It feels perhaps logical to me that they are, but $\{ x\in \Omega : u(x)=0 \}$ is not necessarily of zero Lebesgue measure. In that case, maybe it is then true that $\partial_i u=0$ almost everywhere, but I'm not sure how one would show this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is true that $\nabla u=0$ a.e. on $\{u=0\}$, but unfortunately I cannot give you a reference or proof right now. Maybe someone else can help out.

Comment: The result $\nabla u=0$ a.e. on $\{u=0\}$ can be found in the book by Kinderlehrer & Stampacchia

Comment: If one sets $u^+ = (u+|u|)/2$ then the formula for the derivative follows.

Comment: Thank you! That book was very helpful!

Comment: @HappyChappy28 May I know on which pages in that book did you you find the proof of the result?